# Besides our we sometimes use

Tags: pattern

There is something special about these three numbers. Many other numbers fit this list but these three should be the most common ones.

---

- $2$
- $1666$
- $18364758544493064720$

---

**What is the hidden rule behind the creation of these numbers?**

Comment: The [help center](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for this site is still sitting on the boilerplate after 6 years, so I'm not sure whether the default rules allow for using OEIS; could you let me know?

Comment: Sure, you can use it. But it probably won't be helpful

Comment: It got me as far as the posted answer. ;-)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic my answer did not come from OEIS, but originally from pencil, paper and calculator. The expanded answer came from a short C program. When people post number sequence questions that can be solved by consulting OEIS there is often rather more negative commenting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the hidden rule behind the creation of these numbers?

> Rule: all digits descending in common number systems, as written in Base 10.

> Credit WeatherVane for finding the link to number systems and 2 out of 3. We can close out this puzzle by solving 1666 and thereby confirming the hidden rule:

> System one: Base 2: 10<sub>2</sub> = 2<sub>10</sub>
>  System two: Roman Numerals: MDCLXVI = 1666<sub>10</sub>
>  System three: Base 16: FEDCBA9876543210<sub>16</sub> = 18364758544493064720<sub>10</sub>

This explains the title as well:

> Besides our NUMBER SYSTEM we sometimes use OTHER NUMBER SYSTEMS.

Comment: Completely forgot about this one :D Good job

Answer (score 3):

I can't get the first two, but for the third

> 18364758544493064720<sub>10</sub> = FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF<sub>16</sub> - 0123456789ABCDEF<sub>16</sub>
>
>  I guess there is a similar relationship for other number bases.

---

Edit:

> Simplified to use just descending digits in each number base
>
>  2 10<sub>2</sub> = **2<sub>10</sub>**
>  3 210<sub>3</sub> = 21<sub>10</sub>
>  4 3210<sub>4</sub> = 228<sub>10</sub>
>  5 43210<sub>5</sub> = 2930<sub>10</sub>
>  6 543210<sub>6</sub> = 44790<sub>10</sub>
>  7 6543210<sub>7</sub> = 800667<sub>10</sub>
>  8 76543210<sub>8</sub> = 16434824<sub>10</sub>
>  9 876543210<sub>9</sub> = 381367044<sub>10</sub>
>  10 9876543210<sub>10</sub> = 9876543210<sub>10</sub>
>  11 A9876543210<sub>11</sub> = 282458553905<sub>10</sub>
>  12 BA9876543210<sub>12</sub> = 8842413667692<sub>10</sub>
>  13 CBA9876543210<sub>13</sub> = 300771807240918<sub>10</sub>
>  14 DCBA9876543210<sub>14</sub> = 11046255305880158<sub>10</sub>
>  15 EDCBA9876543210<sub>15</sub> = 435659737878916215<sub>10</sub>
>  16 FEDCBA9876543210<sub>16</sub> = **18364758544493064720<sub>10</sub>**
>
>  But I still have not solved the second part.

Comment: on the right track, but rot13(lbh jrag shegure guna vagraqrq. Jung qb lbh frr vs lbh bayl sbphf ba gur pbairefvba?)

Comment: Yes, the second part is the trickiest

Comment: What does the question title mean?

Comment: Besides our rot13(ahzore flfgrz)....